# Rails erb formatting troubles, phantom spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

Halp! My template is formatting strangely and I can't fathom how/why.

```
<% @poll.questions_all.each do |q| %>
          <td>
            <span class="optionvalue">
              <% if can? :read_full, @poll %>
                <%= resp[:texts][q.id] %>
              <% else %>
                <%= resp[:texts][q.id].nil? ? '' : resp[:texts][q.id].gsub(Question::POISON_WORDS_REGEX, '---') %>
              <% end %>
            </span>
            <% unless q.options.empty? %>
              <%= q.get_matching_option(resp[:texts][q.id])? ": #{q.get_matching_option(resp[:texts][q.id])}" : '' %>
            <% end %>
          </td>
        <% end %>
```

Results in this:

`A : Playgrounds`

No idea where that first space is coming form, and every effort to get rid of it has failed! The generated markup:

```
<td>
   <span class="optionvalue">
       A
   </span>
       : Playgrounds
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `<%- -%>` version of erb tags, these should suppress the extra whitespaces:

```
<%- if can? :read_full, @poll -%>
  <%= resp[:texts][q.id] %>
<%- else -%>
  <%= resp[:texts][q.id].nil? ? '' : resp[:texts][q.id].gsub(Question::POISON_WORDS_REGEX, '---') %>
<%- end -%>
```

I don't recall if you need them in both the opening and ending tags, but I'd suggest playing around with it and see if you can get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Horrible solution, but it works:

```
            <% @poll.questions_all.each do |q| %>
          <td>
            <span class="optionvalue">
              <% if can? :read_full, @poll %>
                <%= resp[:texts][q.id] %></span><%= q.get_matching_option(resp[:texts][q.id])? ": #{q.get_matching_option(resp[:texts][q.id])}" : '' unless q.options.empty? %>
              <% else %>
                <%= resp[:texts][q.id].nil? ? '' : resp[:texts][q.id].gsub(Question::POISON_WORDS_REGEX, '---') %></span><%= q.get_matching_option(resp[:texts][q.id])? ": #{q.get_matching_option(resp[:texts][q.id])}" : '' unless q.options.empty? %>
              <% end %>
          </td>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure `erb` will do the right thing (not add unwanted lines) if you keep everything on one line of HTML.

For this case, and in general, I recommend that you put any logic for generating the content in methods in the view helper file (or if you're feeling lazy, in a code block in the erb, as in this example):

```
<% @poll.questions_all.each do |q| %>
  <% 
    if can? :read_full, @poll
      texts = resp[:texts][q.id]
    else
      texts = (resp[:texts][q.id].nil? ? '' : resp[:texts][q.id].gsub(Question::POISON_WORDS_REGEX, '---'))
    end
    if q.options.empty?
      matching_options = ''
    else 
      matching_options = (q.get_matching_option(resp[:texts][q.id])? ": #{q.get_matching_option(resp[:texts][q.id])}" : '')
    end
  %> 
  <td>
    <span class="optionvalue"><%= texts %></span><%= matching_options %>
  </td>
<% end %>
```